# Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I am building an Angular5 project where I have to use http. I am using observable here, but when I am using 'of'

```
 scope.fetchApi = Observable.of(data);
```

then it is giving me an error:

```
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
```

I had imported `'rxjs/add/observable/of';` also, but same error was there.
I had also tried `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` but it was throwing an error:

```
Module '"eclipse:angular5-example/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
```

You can see my code as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './app.service';
import { FetchApi } from '../models/fetch-api.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import  'rxjs/add/observer/of';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-api',
  templateUrl: './fetch-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fetch-api.component.css']
})
//
  export class FetchApiComponent implements OnInit {

  fetchApi: Observable<FetchApi[]>;

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
     const scope = this;
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe( data => {
         scope.fetchApi = Observable.of(data);
        //this.fetchApi = data;
      });
  };



}
```

Please shed some light on it.

Comment: I think you need to import this `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` instead of `import  'rxjs/add/observer/of';`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: can you post complete error log ?

Comment: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';` & `scope.fetchApi = of(data);`

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: when I am trying to use- import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';  then I am getting an error -"Module '"eclipse:angular5-example/node_modules/rxjs/observable/of"' has no exported member 'of'."

Comment: I am using  rxjs -6.2.0

Comment: I did - `scope.fetchApi= of(data)`, now the error for 'of' has resolved but now getting an error :                                                                                                             `Type 'Observable<FetchApi>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<FetchApi[]>'.
  Type 'FetchApi' is not assignable to type 'FetchApi[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'FetchApi'.`

Comment: can you do this `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';` and `scope.fetchApi = of(data);` then see if it works

Comment: read this document https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md import paths has been changed in rxjs v6

Comment: I did - `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';` and `scope.fetchApi = of(data);` ,now the error for 'of' has resolved but now getting an error : 
`Type 'Observable<FetchApi>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<FetchApi[]>'. Type 'FetchApi' is not assignable to type 'FetchApi[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'FetchApi'.`

Comment: can you post code of `this.userService.getUsers()` method

Comment: `public getUsers() {
    return this.http.get < FetchApi> (this.fetchUrl);
  }`

Comment: I think it should be `public getUsers() { return this.http.get <FetchApi[]> (this.fetchUrl); }`

Comment: Thank you Ajay! It is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

import paths has been changed.

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 13):

Simply return of(data) and not Observable.of(data)